# Py3cairo installed on mac via Brew, but Pygobject3 says 'pycairo' not found on install

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3, pygobject

This is what happens when I try to install py3cairo (because it is already installed):

```
brew install py3cairo
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: py3cairo 1.10.0_3 is already installed
brew upgrade py3cairo
Updating Homebrew...
Error: py3cairo 1.10.0_3 already installed
```

And, yet, when I run the configure batch file for pygobject 3, this is what I get the following output:

```
checking for pkg-config... /opt/local/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.16... yes
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.38.0... yes (version 2.52.3)
checking for FFI... yes
checking for GIO... yes
checking for GI... yes
checking for gobject-introspection... yes
checking for CAIRO... yes
checking for PYCAIRO... no
configure: error: Package requirements (py3cairo >= 1.11.1
        ) were not met:

No package 'py3cairo' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PYCAIRO_CFLAGS
and PYCAIRO_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

The package requirement is that py3cairo >= 1.11.1, but I've tried uninstalling py3cairo with brew and reinstalling it, and it still always installs 1.10.0_3, which makes me think this must be the highest version for mac.

What do I do to get pygobject3 to install on my Mac Seirra?

Answer (score 0):

> configure: error: Package requirements (py3cairo >= 1.11.1

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/py3cairo.rb#L4

> url "https://cairographics.org/releases/pycairo-1.10.0.tar.bz2"

Version is just too old.

Comment: But there's no newer version available.

Comment: Seems so, either they depend upon an unreleased development version or they made a mistake.